# Javascript Class using the window.onunload event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a JavaScript class with methods and properties.

Is it possible to wire this class up to a `pageunload` event?

I am trying to call a method in my class when the user moves pages.

How can I do this?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do, unload events are unreliable at best, can you post what action you want to take?

Comment: Hi Nick, I need to ask the user if I need to save the info he entered in various controls. for now an alert would do.

Comment: +1 @ Nick. In my experience unload events are nasty creatures.

Answer (score 0):

Returning a string from the `onbeforeunload` event handler will show a dialog box.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
test
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
   return "*** Warning: changes are not saved! ***";
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In internet explorer this dialog looks like this:

```
---------------------------
Windows Internet Explorer
---------------------------
Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?

*** Warning: changes are not saved! ***

Press OK to continue, or Cancel to stay on the current page.
---------------------------
OK   Cancel   
---------------------------
```

Your text will be sandwiched between some browser specific text, but that is the only way.

Comment: How do I do this in a class that the class responds to the unload event?

Comment: Can you tell me how you create your "class"? Do you use a framework, or just a function closure or an object with properties? Add some example code to your question and I'll use it in my answer.